# Protecting scripts from users reading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, javascript-security

I have a SOAP WebService with a custom SoapHeader in which I added 2 properties: User and Password, I want to call it using AJAX but I don't want anyone to read them but the application to use it. I've been searching but nothing shows up, Is this possible?

Comment: If you protect it in the source, it'd only take something like Fiddler to be able to see the actual transaction.

Comment: You cannot send data from a client machine and prevent the client from seeing it.  Use OAuth for server-side per-user authentication.

Comment: You can send (md5) hashes instead.